# Passing table as hidden value in html form - weird single/double quote issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php function that outputs a form with button (with post) to download a pdf of the table on the previous page. For some reason, I get weird results if I try to use double quotes, but single quotes in the string declaration work ok (except when I try to feed the butter to js innerhtml).

This works:

```
$form = '<form action="../php/pdf_and_die.php" method="POST" target="_blank">';
$form .= '<input type="hidden" name="table" value="'.$table.'">';
// more lines here
$form .= '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="portrait">';
$form .= '<input type="submit" value="     '.$button_name.'     " class="button"></form>';
```

But this doesn't:

```
$form = "<form action='../php/pdf_and_die.php' method='POST' target='_blank'>";
$form .= "<input type='hidden' name='table' value='{$table}'>";
// more lines here
$form .= "<input type='submit' value='{$button_name}     ' class='button'></form>";
```

When I try to do the second way with double quotes, the table is displayed before the button. [screenshot with double quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg92r.jpg)

Shouldn't single/double quotes be mostly the same as far as php and html are concerned, as long as they're used consistently? (barring differences like variables in strings like "foo{$bar}").

This wouldn't be a problem and I would just go with the working single quotes for the string declaration inside the php function, except that on another page, I have a pulldown menu with onclick and a js function that replaces one of these buttons for another based on the academic session the user chooses, and innerhtml doesn't seem to like the single quote (double quotes inside) option. [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L5n3.jpg)

On the page that displays the button: (abbreviated for readability)

```
<?php
    foreach ($sessions as $session) {
        // string of attendance table
        $session_table = get_class_attn_table($course, $acad_year, $session);

        // get_pdf_form_button returns a string
        $attn_button = get_pdf_form_button($session_table);

        // add the output html to the array as a string
        $sessions_text[] = $attn_button;
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_session() {
        var x = "" + document.getElementById("session_select").value;
        var session1_text = "<?php echo $sessions_text[0];?>";
        var session2_text = "<?php echo $sessions_text[1];?>";

        if (x == "1") {
            document.getElementById("change_session").innerHTML = session1_text;
        }
        else if (x == "2") {
            document.getElementById("change_session").innerHTML = session2_text;
        }
    }
</script>

<select id="session_select" onchange="toggle_session()">
    <option selected value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I'm pretty new to php and js, so maybe I missed something simple.

Comment: What is inside the `$table` variable?

Comment: The table that the database/php fills: "<table><thead><tr><th>Student></th><th>ID</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr> ...(rows here) ...</tbody></table>"

Comment: If it contains any quotes, that may be your problem.

Comment: Oh, good point, I have some class identifiers in there for css. So it sounds like the quote type I use there matters even after I've generated the table and use the variable in other contexts, I had only been thinking of the quote type compatibility when I declared the var to hold the table string, not when I passed the table on. I'll fiddle with it, and see if that helps

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your second problem (with the dropdown menu), but it sounds like it might be related. Could you add more details?

Comment: I think they are. The problem is that innerhtml seems to be very picky about the string I give it in terms of quotes and escape characters before quotes. I just took out all internal quotes in the table, and now innerhtml and the pdf_button_form are both happy with the string. Every other configuration of single/double quotes was finicky, but maybe I'll just have the table class be quote-less as a rule (since html is fine with it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As had been worked out in the comments, the `$table` variable did have some quotes in it, which messed with the HTML.

Solutions for problematic quotes:

- Use the PHP built-in function [`addslashes(string)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).
- Replace double quotes (`"`) with the HTML character entity `&quot;`, and single quotes (`'`) with the HTML character entity `&apos;`. [Character entity reference chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)
- Get rid of the quotes.

Comment: Yes, I went through each step (table generation, function to generate the button, function to print the table as pdf) and took out the internal quotes. There was still a bit of a problem, then I realized the value=$table still needed the internal quotes because the variable has spaces and I could only get away with no internal quotes for those attributes if they didn't have spaces. So my problem is finally solved, and the pdf button, pdf wrapper, and innerhtml js are playing nice together. Thank you!